# Problem with composer not autoloading certain package

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a package I created that I included with composer called ShinePHP (https://packagist.org/packages/adammcgurk/shine-php#0.0.4), and it has been working fine being autoloaded etc..., but right now the autoload just all of a sudden shut off. There is no reason for this, I didn't touch the composer.json file, I really didn't touch *anything* with the library, I'm just getting the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ShinePHP\EasyHttp' not found in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/manager-reporting/src/index.php:12
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/manager-reporting/src/index.php
>   on line 12

Here is how that code is being called:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
session_start();

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'model/Page.php';
require_once 'model/Auth.php';

use ShinePHP\{Crud, CrudException, HandleData, HandleDataException, EasyHttp, EasyHttpException};
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

try {
    EasyHttp::checkHttps();
} catch (EasyHttpException $ehe) {
    // Google Analytics
    echo $ehe->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

I know it is a problem with this particular library, because I also have PHPMailer installed here with Composer, and I just tried instantiating PHPMailer using:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

And it worked no problem.

I've ran:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

And got this response:

```
Generating autoload files
```

**Why is my autoload broken for my ShinePHP package?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoloading rules in your package ([`adammcgurk/shine-php`](https://github.com/ShineSolar/ShinePHP/blob/67747b793ce67dbe2d5d5731978aa8bd4e088e8e/composer.json#L13-L16)) are incorrect. Since your classes are inside of `src/ShinePHP` directory your autolading rules should look like that:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "ShinePHP\\": "src/ShinePHP/"
    }
},
```